# Hide empty sub-report from main report in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

On my reports, there is one sub report, I set the "suppress blank report" already , but it still causes an empty space when output.As seen in the figure below, although the empty value appears in the first box, it takes up space on the screen.

[image]

how can i block this space for the first box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the subreport and select Format Subreport > Subreport tab > check 'Suppress Blank Subreport'.It's not useless because of value comes from table.